# Push notification not working on actual device

Tags: flutter, push-notification

I am developing a flutter app using push notification with this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) from flutter. fcm token is generated successfully and I checked the database and it's updated but doesn't receive anything even I used firebase console

weird part is its working on iOS simulator and android so I can't check where the problem is. Hope someone could help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this, I forgot to upload .p8 authkey in firebase console